# Multiply all elements of an array by a number? (Rust)

Tags: arrays, rust

I have an array of four elements:

```
let mut arr: [u8; 4] = [0xff, 0x4d, 0xff, 0xff];
```

I want to slightly change the final values (Except the last one) with a random float. For now, let's say this random float isn't random, it's the number `0.92`.

I could do this:

```
let random_float = 0.92;
arr[0] *= random_float;
arr[1] *= random_float;
arr[2] *= random_float;
```

But it's slow to write, plus it's basically the same line of code three times with the index value changing. So is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Please provide code that compiles. Unless asking about a compile error (and in that case provide the code that produces the error).

Comment: Use a `map` . This will do what you want, but for all elements. Use a slice, this will select the elements that you want. Combine them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You couldn't actually write

```
arr[0] *= random_float;
arr[1] *= random_float;
arr[2] *= random_float;
```

as `arr[0]` has type `u8` and `random_float` has type `f64`. Rust won't let you multiply those two types because it's not entirely clear what the desired result is. You need to cast the numbers between each others' types to work with them:

```
arr[0] = (arr[0] as f64 * random_float) as u8;
```

But that is, as you pointed out, quite tedious.

You can use a loop instead:

```
for b in arr[0..3].iter_mut() {
    *b = (*b as f64 * random_float) as u8;
}
```

Or the equivalent one-liner with `for_each`:

```
arr[0..3].iter_mut().for_each(|b| *b = (*b as f64 * random_float) as u8);
```

Comment: In order to exactly match the question (don't touch the last element), I think you need [`.take(3)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) between `.iter_mut()` and `.for_each()`, or use `arr[0..3]`.

Comment: @prog-fh Oh I must have unconsciously skipped that parenthetical, thanks for pointing it out!